# How can I mock the Azure Blob storage blob.WithVersion(versionId) function?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, moq

I am having issues mocking one particular function from Azure.Storage.Blobs; I would like to be able to mock blob.WithVersion(versionId) but can't figure out how to.

When I don't mock the function, I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uri')

Stack Trace: 
BlobUriBuilder.ctor(Uri uri, Boolean trimBlobNameSlashes)
BlobUriBuilder.ctor(Uri uri)
BlobClient.WithVersion(String versionId)
```

I tried to mock it directly as follows:

```
mockBlobClient.Setup(x => x.WithVersion(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockBlobClient.Object);
```

But got this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x => x.WithVersion(It.IsAny<string>())
Non-overridable members (here: BlobClient.WithVersion) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

I have used BlobsModelFactory in other scenarios to mock blob functions but can't figure out how to use it in this case.

Does anyone have any tips? Thanks!